# How can I rearrange array items moving dependencies on top?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have the following `array` where each item may (or may not depend) on another one:

```php
$test = array(
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => 'b'
    ),
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
);
```

I want to move (or make another `array`) with **dependencies are moved at the top**. First `a`, then `b` and `d` (both depend on `a`) and finally `c` which depends on `b`. The order of `b` and `d` is irrelevant:

```php
$rearranged = array(
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => 'b'
    ),
);
```

I'm pretty sure that this is a quite common situation and before **reinventing the wheel** and waste time I'd like to know if there is any data structure that can do the job for me.

**EDIT**: forgot to say that circular references should be detected (`b` depends on `a` that depends on `b` should not be allowed).

Comment: If a circular reference is detected, how do you want the code to respond? Throw a fatal error? Or perhaps place such nodes on the bottom of the list?

Comment: @Ultimater fatal error, exception... should not be allowed.

Comment: @Gremo Do you want me to edit my answer for hierarchy greater that 2nd dimension ... ?

Answer (score 7):

This is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). If you consider your structure as a graph, where "a depends on b" is equal to a directed edge from vertex b to vertex a, you should just do a topological sort to get your answer.

Implementation of topological sort can be done like this:

let graph[ n ][ n ] be the graph corresponding to your array (graph[ i ][ j ] = 1 means j depends on i).

1. *ans* = {} // empty sequence
2. *income* = **new array**[ n ]
3. *income*[ i ] = number of edges incoming to vertex i
4. *used* = **new array**[ n ] // shows if any vertex has already been used, default all false
5. **while** *ans*.size != n // there are still unused vertexes
    
   **do begin** 
   **find** i **s.t.** *income*[ i ] == 0 and *used*[ i ] == false 
   *ans*.append( i ) 
   **for each** j s.t. *graph*[ i ][ j ] == 1 **decrement** *income*[ j ] 
   **end**
6. **return** ans

Comment: That sounds good. Is there any facility in PHP to do topological sorting?

Comment: @Gremo: I'm not good at PHP, but it's easy to implement. I'll add implementation description.

Answer (score 3):

[array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) will help you here..

```
<?php

    $test = array(
        'c' => array(
            'depends' => 'b'
        ),
        'a' => array(),
        'b' => array(
            'depends' => 'a'
        ),
        'd' => array(
            'depends' => 'a'
        )
    );

    function sortArray($array= array())
         {
            $depend = array();
            foreach ($array as $key => $value)
            {

                if (isset($value['depends']))
                {
                    $depend[$key] = $value['depends'];
                }
                else
                {
                   $depend[$key] = null;
                }

            }
            return $depend;
         }


         function findCircularReference($array)
         {
            foreach($array as $key=>$value)
            {
               if(isset($array[$value]) && ($array[$value] == $key))
               {
                  return true;
               }
            }
            return false;
         }

         $depend = sortArray($test);
         $checkReference  = findCircularReference($depend);

         if( ! $checkReference)
         {
             array_multisort($depend, SORT_ASC, $test);
         }
         else
         {
             trigger_error("Circular reference", E_USER_ERROR);
         }


         print_r($test);
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain how multisort works with 2 inputs? You solution seems so simple...

Comment: Forgot to say, will this fail with a circular reference (cycle)?

Comment: This solution uses a faulty algorithm which cannot sort higher than the 2nd dimension. My algorithm is able to work beyond the 2nd dimension.

Comment: @Gremo edited my answer for circular reference ....multisorts works only with one input .... and dimension with which tou have to sort the array .... do you want me to edit my answer anymore...?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and works:

Basically it loops through each node and checks the depth of that node from the top of the tree and appends the value to a new array `$ar`. Then it sorts `$test` based on the depth level of each node stored in `$ar` using `array_multisort()`.

```
<?php
$test = array(
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => 'b'
    ),
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => 'a'
    ),
);


function getNodeLevel($ar,$n,$ref=array())
{
       if(!isset($ar[$n]['depends'])){return 0;}
       if(in_array($n,$ref)){return -1;}
       $ref[]=$n;
       $r=getNodeLevel($ar,$ar[$n]['depends'],$ref);
       return ($r==-1?-1:$r+1);
}


$ar=array();

foreach($test as $i=>$tmp)
{
    $ar[]=getNodeLevel($test,$i);
}

if(!in_array(-1,$ar))
{
    array_multisort($ar,SORT_ASC,$test);
    print_r($test);
}else{
     trigger_error("Circular reference detected.", E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1) but it's implicit in the question that I only need 1 level in the hierarchy.

Comment: *edits* now it will throw an error if it detects a circular reference as per your answer to my question.

Comment: No it wasn't. It was implicit in your question the other way -- that you need more than 1 level in your hierarchy based on this part: `First a, then b and d (both depend on a) and finally c which depends on b. The order of b and d is irrelevant` You said finally c because it depends on b which in turn depends on a.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use the most basic dependancy sorting, and have this as a working solution. Tested multiple variations and works sound thus far.

```
private function getSorted($type)
{
    uasort($this->assets[$type], array($this, 'sortDependancies'));
    return $this->assets[$type];
}

 /**
 * Sorting utility function via uasort from getSorted
 * 
 * @returns sort order
 */
private function sortDependancies($a, $b)
{
    if ( is_array($b['dependant']) && in_array($a['alias'], $b['dependant'])) return -1;

    if ( $a['alias'] == $b['dependant'] ) return -1;

    return 1;
}
```

I created this for use within an array of js and css asset collection object.

```
protected $assets = array(
    'stylesheets' => array(
            'main' => array(
                'alias' => 'main',
                'path' => 'somepath.less',
                'dependant' => 'bootstrap'
            ),
            'bootstrap' => (
                'alias' => 'bootstrap',
                'path' => 'bootstrap.css',
                'dependant' => NULL
            )
        ),
    'javascripts' => array()
);
```

so I would call the $type ie either 'stylesheets' or 'javascripts' within getSorted()

I also made it so it could work with multiple dependancies using an array for the 'dependant' item instead of a string.

If this context needs to be a simplified let me know, I did create this within an object after all...

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I have been inspired by the [Wikipedia page Topological Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).
So I made some self algorithm.

```
/**
 * Class Top
 *
 * @package Lib\Sort
 */
class Top
{
    /**
     * Unsorted nodes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_nodes = array();

    /**
     * Nodes structure
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_structure = array();

    /**
     * Stored nodes
     *
     * @var array|null
     */
    protected $_sortedNodes;

    /**
     * Stored nodes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_level = 0;

    /**
     * Status of mode "single non-edge node"
     *
     * @var bool
     * @see setModeSingleNonEdgeNode()
     */
    protected $_singleNonEdgeNode = true;

    /**
     * Get status of "Single non-edge node" mode
     *
     * @return boolean
     * @see setModeSingleNonEdgeNode()
     */
    public function isModeSingleNonEdgeNode()
    {
        return $this->_singleNonEdgeNode;
    }

    /**
     * Set status of "Single non-edge node" mode
     *
     * This status means that sorting will move only first non-edged node to top.
     * Rest non-edge nodes will be added according to sorting in _nodes property
     * In case it will FALSE all nodes will be moved to top.
     *
     * @param boolean $flag
     * @return $this
     */
    public function enableModeSingleNonEdgeNode($flag)
    {
        $this->_singleNonEdgeNode = (bool)$flag;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add node
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param array  $dependsOn
     * @throws Exception
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addNode($name, array $dependsOn = array())
    {
        if (null !== $this->_sortedNodes) {
            throw new Exception('Nodes already sorted.');
        }
        $this->_nodes[$name]     = $name;
        $this->_structure[$name] = $dependsOn;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Sort
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSortedNodes()
    {
        if (null === $this->_sortedNodes) {
            $this->_sortedNodes = array();
            //insert non-edged nodes
            $this->_performNonEdgedNodes();
            //insert edged nodes
            $this->_performEdgedNodes();
        }
        return $this->_sortedNodes;
    }

    /**
     * Move node into sorted list
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @throws Exception
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _moveNodeToSortedList($name)
    {
        $node = $this->_takeNode($name);
        if ($node) {
            $this->_sortedNodes[] = $node;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("The node '$name' has already been taken.");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Take node from the list
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function _takeNode($name)
    {
        if (!isset($this->_nodes[$name])) {
            return null;
        }
        $node = $this->_nodes[$name];
        unset($this->_nodes[$name]);
        return $node;
    }

    /**
     * Perform node sorting
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _performNode($name)
    {
        $node = $this->_takeNode($name);
        if (null === $node) {
            return $this;
        }
        foreach ($this->_structure[$node] as $depNode) {
            $this->_checkCycledEdges($node, $depNode);
            $this->_performNode($depNode);
        }
        $this->_sortedNodes[] = $node;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Check cycled edges
     *
     * @param string $node
     * @param string $edgeNode
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _checkCycledEdges($node, $edgeNode)
    {
        if (in_array($node, $this->_structure[$edgeNode])) {
            throw new Exception("Cyclic dependencies between $edgeNode and $node.");
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Perform edged nodes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _performEdgedNodes()
    {
        while (!empty($this->_nodes)) {
            $name = current($this->_nodes);
            $this->_performNode($name);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Perform non-edged nodes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _performNonEdgedNodes()
    {
        foreach ($this->_structure as $name => $edges) {
            if (!$edges) {
                $this->_moveNodeToSortedList($name);
                if ($this->isModeSingleNonEdgeNode()) {
                    //to add only first node and to add rest non-edge nodes according to sorting in _nodes property
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And made tests for this class:

```
<?php
namespace Lib\Sort;

/**
 * Class TopTest
 *
 * @package Lib\Sort
 */
class TopTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testBasicSorting()
    {
        $test = new Top();
        $test->addNode('A');
        $test->addNode('B', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('C', array('B', 'D'));
        $test->addNode('D', array('F'));
        $test->addNode('E', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('F', array('A'));
        $test->addNode('G');
        $this->assertTrue($test->isModeSingleNonEdgeNode());
        $actual   = $test->getSortedNodes();
        $expected = array('A', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'G');
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

    /**
     * Test sorting of last node with many edges
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function testLastNodeSorting()
    {
        $test = new Top();
        $test->addNode('A', array());
        $test->addNode('B', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('C', array('B', 'D'));
        $test->addNode('D', array('F'));
        $test->addNode('E', array('A'));
        $test->addNode('F', array('A', 'E'));
        $actual   = $test->getSortedNodes();
        $expected = array('A', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'C');
        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
    }

    /**
     * Test sorting disabled mode "Single non-edge node"
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function testDisabledSingleNonEdgesSorting()
    {
        $test = new Top();
        $test->addNode('A');
        $test->addNode('B', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('C', array('B', 'D'));
        $test->addNode('D', array('F'));
        $test->addNode('E', array('A'));
        $test->addNode('F', array('A', 'E'));
        $test->addNode('G');
        $test->enableModeSingleNonEdgeNode(false);
        $actual   = $test->getSortedNodes();
        $expected = array('A', 'G', 'E', 'F', 'B', 'D', 'C');
        $this->assertEquals($actual, $expected);
    }

    /**
     * Test exception for cyclic nodes
     *
     * @expectedException \Lib\Sort\Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage Cyclic dependencies between E and F.
     */
    public function testCyclicSortingFailure()
    {
        $test = new Top();
        $test->addNode('A', array());
        $test->addNode('B', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('C', array('B', 'D'));
        $test->addNode('D', array('F'));
        $test->addNode('E', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('F', array('A', 'E'));
        $test->getSortedNodes();
        //expected an exception
    }

    /**
     * Test exception for cyclic nodes
     *
     * @expectedException \Lib\Sort\Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage Nodes already sorted.
     */
    public function testAddNodeAfterSortingFailure()
    {
        $test = new Top();
        $test->addNode('A', array());
        $test->addNode('B', array('A', 'F'));
        $test->addNode('C', array('B', 'D'));
        $test->addNode('D', array('F'));
        $test->addNode('E', array('A'));
        $test->addNode('F', array('A', 'E'));
        $test->getSortedNodes();
        $test->addNode('H', array('E'));
        //expected an exception
    }
}
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone.