# How can I rearrange array items moving dependencies on top if dependencies is array?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have the following array where each item may (or may not depend) on another one:

```
$test = array(
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => array('b')
    ),
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => array('a', 'd')
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => array('a')
    )
);
```

i want output result

```
$test = array(
    'a' => array(),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => array('a')
    ),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => array('a', 'd')
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => array('b')
    )
);
```

this code have problem resemble this question "[How can I rearrange array items moving dependencies on top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901159/how-can-i-rearrange-array-items-moving-dependencies-on-top/33773167?noredirect=1#comment55314193_33773167)"

but have different is if depend have multiple dependencies function array_multisort cannot sort it.

Comment: Whats your expected output

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Uchiha i have edit question already sorry.

Comment: The term you are looking for is [Linear extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$test = array(
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => array('b')
    ),
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => array('a', 'd')
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => array('a')
    )
);

$rearranged = array();
$test_left = $test;
do {
  $resolved = false; // Check for rounds without any move
  reset($test_left);
  while (list($key, $val) = each($test_left)) {
    $move = false;
    if (isset($val['depends']) && !empty($val['depends'])) {
      // Dependencies count must be not greater than rearranged array length
      $depends = count($val['depends']) <= count($rearranged);

      // All dependencies must be set in rearranged array already
      while ($depends && (list(, $dep_key) = each($val['depends']))) {
        if (!array_key_exists($dep_key, $rearranged)) {
          $depends = false;
        }
      }

      $move = $depends;
    } else {
      // Independent items moves to top
      $move = true;
    }

    if ($move) {
      $rearranged[$key] = $val;
      unset($test_left[$key]);
      $resolved = true;
    }
  }
}
while ($resolved && !empty($test_left));

if (empty($test_left)) {
  echo 'Success<pre>';
  print_r($rearranged);
  echo '</pre>';
} else {
  echo 'There are some unresolved dependencies';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for, though your question is very vague:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    'c' => array(
        'depends' => array('b')
    ),
    'a' => array(),
    'b' => array(
        'depends' => array('a', 'd')
    ),
    'd' => array(
        'depends' => array('a')
    )
);

$output = array();

foreach ($input as $dependant=>$settings) {
    if (   is_array($settings) 
        && isset($settings['depends']) 
        && is_array($settings['depends'])) {
        foreach ($settings['depends'] as $dependent) {
            $output[$dependent]['dependent'][] = $dependant;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

The output is:

```
array(3) {
  'b' =>
  array(1) {
    'dependent' =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(1) "c"
    }
  }
  'a' =>
  array(1) {
    'dependent' =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(1) "b"
      [1] =>
      string(1) "d"
    }
  }
  'd' =>
  array(1) {
    'dependent' =>
    array(1) {
      [0] =>
      string(1) "b"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry coz my english very bad. but thank you for you help. but not currect yet.

Comment: @NontAtCalypso Your English is pretty good, actually, as it seems. So welcome to SO! Hope the above is what you are looking for.