# PHP sorting dependency array list - Topological Sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of files with dependencies.  I need them sorted so all dependent files are indexed after their dependency.  I've made a lot of attempts with forEach loops, while loops, but once a dependency is moved, the loops don't account for previous iterations and indexed elements wind up out of order.

I have a simplified version of the data I am working with:

```
$dependencies = array(
        array(
            'handle'    => 'jquery',
            'requires'  => array(
                'jquery-core',
                'jquery-migrate'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'jquery-migrate',
            'requires'  => array()
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'common',
            'requires'  => array(
                'utils',
                'jquery',
                'jquery-core',
                'jquery-migrate',
                'jquery-effects-core',
                'backbone'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'jquery-effects-core',
            'requires'  => array(
                'jquery',
                'jquery-core',
                'jquery-migrate'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'backbone',
            'requires'  => array(
                'underscore',
                'jquery'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'underscore',
            'requires'  => array()
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'utils',
            'requires'  => array()
        ),
        array(
            'handle'    => 'jquery-core',
            'requires'  => array()
        )
    );
```

If [handle] appears in an elements [requires] array, that element needs to be moved ahead of the indicated [requires] element, all while maintaining any other dependencies previously accounted for.

```
    function moveEle(&$array, $a, $b){
        $out            = array_splice($array, $a, 1);
        array_splice($array, $b, 0, $out);
    }

    foreach($dependencies as $i=>$dependency){
        if( count($dependency['requires'])>0 ){
            $itr        = count($dependency['requires']);
            echo $dependency['handle']."<br/>";
            while($itr > 0){
                // loop through current files required files
                foreach( $dependency['requires'] as $k=>$dep ){
                    // loop through dependencies array again to find required file handle
                    echo "-- " . $dep . "<br/>";
                    foreach($dependencies as $j=>$jDep){
                        // $j = index in dependencies array of required file, $i = index in dependencies array of dependent file.
                        if( $dep === $jDep['handle'] && $j > $i ){
                            echo "found " . $jDep['handle'] . "@ " . $j."<br/>";
                            moveEle(&$dependencies, $j, $i );
                        }
                    }
                    $itr--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm taking it there is probably some recursive way to do this that is a little beyond my scope of skill at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I did find this solution:
[PHP Order array based on elements dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711720/php-order-array-based-on-elements-dependency)
which does work, however, once the array gets to 150 files (the actual data size), it times out or takes an incredibly long time. I'd like a more efficient solution, if one exists.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the desired results with this:

```
/*
        *
        *   @description        return nested array with all dependencies & sub dependencies
        *
    **/
    function getWithDependencies($dependency, $collection){
        $helper     = new Insight_WP_Scripts_Helpers();
        $set = array(
            'handle'        => $dependency,
            'dependencies'  => array()
        );

        foreach($collection as $index=>$data){
            if( $data['handle'] === $set['handle'] ){
                // echo "<h4>".$data['handle']."</h4>";
                if(count($helper->getDependencies($set, $collection))>0){
                    $dependencies       = $helper->getDependencies($set['handle'], $collection);
                    foreach($dependencies as $i=>$dependency){
                        // echo $dependency . "<br/>";
                        $set['dependencies'][$i]        = array(
                            'handle'        => $dependency,
                            'dependencies'  => array()
                        );
                        if( count($helper->getDependencies($dependency, $collection)) > 0 ){
                            foreach(getWithDependencies($dependency, $collection) as $k=>$dep){
                                $set['dependencies'][$i]['dependencies']    = $dep;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $set;
    }

    /*
        *
        *   @description        recursively sorts dependencies to depth returned by getWithDependencies()
        *
    **/
    function sortDependency($data,&$collection){
        $helper     = new Insight_WP_Scripts_Helpers();
        foreach($collection as $index=>$inst){
            if( $inst['handle'] === $data['handle'] && count($data['dependencies'])>0){
                // iterate over each dependency
                foreach( $inst['dependencies'] as $i=>$dependency ){
                    // iterate over the collection to find dependencies position for comparison against dependent file.
                    foreach( $collection as $k=>$kdep ){
                        if($kdep['handle'] === $dependency['handle'] && $index < $k){
                            $helper->moveArrayElement($collection, $k, $index);
                            // call recursively to search full depth
                            if( count($dependency['dependencies']) > 0 ){
                                sortDependency($dependency,$collection);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach( $dependencies as $index=>$data ){
        $fullDependencies       = array();
        foreach($dependencies as $i=>$dependency){
            $fullDependencies[]     = getWithDependencies($dependency['handle'], $dependencies);
        }
    }
    $_fullDependencies = $fullDependencies;
    foreach( $fullDependencies as $index=>$data ){
        sortDependency($data,$_fullDependencies);
    }
    $fullDependencies = $_fullDependencies;
return $fullDependencies;
```